# Where should stripe be integrated in single page application with django backend

Tags: django, angularjs, stripe-payments

I am new to stripe integration. I've looked at couple of examples but I'm unsure where I should integrate stripe in my application. My front-end is in Angular and the backend is in django. Should I integrate stripe in Angular code base or django code base?

Answer (score 4):

Both. Front-end: either use Checkout (Embedded Form) or their Custom Form. This will spit out a token that you must process on the server side. If you are using routing or have a complex app, then you probably want a library to abstract away from Stripe's default behaviors, as it uses a simple form action. This will cause a reload or redirection from the page which could be a problem if you don't want to leave the app. I prefer this lightweight wrapper, though others exist: https://github.com/tobyn/angular-stripe-checkout

Server: You include their library for your language (Python if you want) in a script written to process the token. This is what actually sends the charge to Stripe. Just doing the front-end side only sends them a token which shows up in the logs but does nothing. This is where you create a new customer, charge, subscription, etc. according to the API for your language.

Once you've got that set up, then you'll probably want to listen for their webhooks, save the user that is created in your backend with its created from the initial payment, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate it both in the front-end and back-end, but if it's a single page app and the backend is REST-ful it makes sense to do it in Angular

See this article for example: https://www.airpair.com/javascript/integrating-stripe-into-angular-app